# Efficiently pairing objects in lists based on key

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

So, here's the deal. 
(My current use-case is in C#, but I'm also interested in the general algorithmic case)
I am given two Arrays of objects (I don't get to alter the code that creates these arrays, unfortunately).
Each object has (as part of it) a .Name property, a string.
These strings are unique per object, and they have zero or one matching strings in the other object.
What I need to do is efficiently pair these objects based on that string, into some sort of collection that allows me access to the paired objects.  The strings need to match exactly to be considered a match, so I don't need any Upper or CaseInsensitive, etc.
Sadly, these lists are not sorted.
The lists themselves are maybe 30-50 items, but I need to repeat the algorithm on thousands of these array-pairs in a row, so efficiency is important.

Since I know that there's 0 or 1 match, and I know that most of them will be 1 match, I feel like there's a more efficient algorithm than x*y (Foreach item in x, foreach item in y, if x=y then x and y are a match)

I believe the most likely options are:

Keep the unsorted list and just do x*y, but drop items from the list once I've found them so I don't check ones already-found, 
OR:
Convert both to Dictionaries and then do an indexed lookup on each (array2[currentArray1Item])
OR:
Sort the lists myself (Array.Sort()), and then having sorted arrays I can probably do something clever like jump to the index in B where I'd expect to find it (wherever it was in A) and then move up or down based on string until I either find it or pass where it should've been.

Then once that's done I need to figure out how to store it, I suppose I can make a custom ObjectPair class that just holds objects A and B.  No need to do anything fancy here, since I'm just going to ForEach on the pairs.

So the questions are: 
Are any of the above algorithms the fastest way to do this (if not, what is?) and is there some existing C# structure that'd conveniently hold the found pairs?

**EDIT:** Array.Sort() is a method that exists, so I don't need to convert the array to List to sort. Good to know. Updated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question I have is: how much efficiency do we gain from the special handling if it requires us to sort *both* input arrays? According to the documentation for [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc.aspx), it is `O(n log n)` on average and `O(n ^ 2)` in the worst case (quicksort). Once we have both arrays sorted, we then have another `O(n)` amount of work because we have to loop through the first one.

I interpret this to mean that the overall amount of work might actually *increase* because of the number of iterations required to sort, then process. This of course would be a different story if you could guarantee sorted arrays at the start, but as you said you cannot. (I should also note that you would need to create a custom `IComparer<T>` implementation to pass to `Array.Sort` so it knows to use the `.Name` property. That's not runtime work, but it's still work :-)

You might consider using a LINQ join, which only iterates the inner array a single time ([see here for psuedocode](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/JoinOperator.ashx)). This is as opposed to the nested `foreach` statements, which would iterate the inner array for each element of the outer array. It's about as efficient as it can be in the general case and doesn't introduce the complexity of the special handling you suggested.

Here is an example implementation:

```
var pairs =
    from item1 in array1
    join item2 in array2 on item1.Name equals item2.Name
    select new { item1, item2 };

foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    // Use the pair somehow
}
```

That very clearly states what you are doing with the data and also gives you an anonymous type representing each pair (so you don't have to invent a pairing). If you do end up going a different route, I would be interested in how it compares to this approach.

Comment: I rather like the Anonymous object pair result you used here, I'd forgotten to consider that option for the eventual resultset of matches.
I will try running this LINQ join approach, and running a sort-and-binary-search, next to eachother to see which works better for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sort the second array using `Array.Sort` method, then match objects in the second `Array` using `Binary Search Algorithm`.

Generally, for 30-50 items this would be a little faster than brute force x*y.

Comment: Oh, Array has a Sort itself, thought I had to convert to List<>

Comment: Another approach would be to sort both arrays. After that, when you iterate through first array, you also iterate through the second one (side by side) by increasing it's index while (name1 > name2). Then you do not have to use binary search to match the elements.